# Easiest Way To Move a Single Page DotNetNuke Page From Dev to Live?

Tags: sql, content-management-system, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-module, dotnetnuke-7

We have a DotNetNuke installation that we have on a dev environment and we are setting it up on our live server now. Everything looks great and is working just fine that regard. We were wondering if it was possible that once a page has been updated or created on our dev server and we're happy with it, is there a simple and easy way to push that page to the live server?

1. Dev has it's own database.
2. Live has a different database to itself.

We have seen some programs like SQL Sync but we do not want to push all pages from dev to live because there might still be some pages being worked on when another one finishes so we must have a way to push individual pages instead of everything.

Thank you so much for any help!

Answer (score 1):

you can use Exporting And Importing feature in dotnetnuke it allows you to export a single  page or whole web site  you can follow this links for helo

**[Page import export](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HK7Yraho52s)**

[Great article to look for](http://www.ventrian.com/blog/exporting-and-importing-dotnetnuke-portals)